# Armbian with KDE desktop reboots at KDE splash screen

Tags: kde, armbian

I have Armbian running on a Pine A64 LTS V2 on an eMMC. All works on the headless part A-OK until the boot process gets to the KDE splash screen, then a power cycle occurs. Is there a way to stop the Armbian handoff to the desktop environment so I can redo the install from armbian-config? Armbian was updated to its newest version yesterday, and only change after that was to start the config install of the desktop environment.